# Lagom: Persistence failure when replaying events for persistenceId

Tags: scala, cassandra, lagom

I am using lagom for building a, small sample application. I am following the structure of "**hello-world"** lagom sample application. But whenever I am trying to run the application, I am facing, bellow error:

```
[error] a.c.s.PersistentShardCoordinator - Persistence failure when replaying events for persistenceId [/sharding/TwitterEntityCoordinator]. Last known sequence number [0]
akka.pattern.CircuitBreaker$$anon$1: Circuit Breaker Timed out.
[error] a.c.s.PersistentShardCoordinator - Persistence failure when replaying events for persistenceId [/sharding/kafkaProducer-tweetsCoordinator]. Last known sequence number [0]
```

Still, I am not getting what is the meaning of this error and to resolve them?? Because, I am using `Apache Kafka` also, and my messages are successfully stored into topic but in logs, this error show every time.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @TimMoore need to post whole code or Entity code only ?

Comment: Probably just the entity in the question, but if you have the code on GitHub and can add a link, that would be helpful too.

Comment: Sure @TimMoore, click on this github link https://github.com/knoldus/lagom-spike.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara How did you manage to solve this problem?